# Send an excel file from database to excel without writing a file

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, sql-server-2008

I am working in VB.Net 2013. This is a desktop application.

I have an Excel document (.xlsx) stored in a SQL server database as binary data.  I would like to be able to send this 'file' to excel with having to write it out as a temp file.

Is this possible?

Currently I have it working by writing a file as follows, but I would prefer to not have to write the temp file

```
    Dim dtExcel As New DataTable
    Dim oDaEx As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [tblTV4] Where oPath = '" & txtPath.Text & "'", oCon)
    Try
        oDaEx.Fill(dtExcel)

        Dim oRow As DataRow = dtExcel.Rows(0)
        Dim filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\" & oRow!oFilename
        Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.Create)
        Dim bw As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs)

        bw.Write(oRow!Excel)
        bw.Close()
        fs.Close()

        Process.Start(filename)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: This is a desktop appliction

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add information. You should never need to directly reply to your own questions or answers here on SO.